# show that ${ x^4+x+1 \in GF(2^2)[x] }$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

show that ${ x^4+x+1 \in GF(2^2)[x] }$ is the product of tow quadratic polynomials .

"i tried to factor ${ x^4+x+1 }$ but don't know "

Comment: I did this as an example in the last part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it isn't too hard to do this by direct computation. Since $x^4+x+1$ is monic, suppose that $a,b,c,d\in\mathrm{GF}(4)$ with
$$x^4+x+1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d).$$
Expand the RHS, compare coefficients and solve for $a,b,c,d$. It will be helpful to remind yourself of what the elements of $\mathrm{GF}(4)$ look like.

Comment: The constant term should be $bd$. Now, sort the terms based on the power of $x$, then equate coefficients on the RHS and LHS.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to solve it like 
${ (x^2+bx+1)(x^2+dx+1)=x^4+x+1 }$

x-terms→b+d=1

x³-terms→b+d=0

contradiction !

not factorisable !